# Closures of the following subsets of $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$:

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I'm trying to work out how to compute the closures of the following sets:

1. $$\left\{a ∈ ℓ^1(\mathbb{N}) \,\middle|\, \sum |a_j|^2 \le 1 \right\}$$
2. $$\left\{a ∈ ℓ^1(\mathbb{N}) \,\middle|\, \sum |a_j|^2 < \infty \right\}$$

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: It's probably going to be some thing like the unit ball, or the whole space, or they're already closed, or something like that. So make a guess, start trying to prove it, (Cauchy Schwarz might end up being useful), and you either prove it or else the problem you encounter trying to prove it gives you a condition to impose that'll be the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $T$ on $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ by $ T(a) = \sum_{j} |a_j|^2 $. Then

$$ |T(b) - T(a)| \leq \sum_j |a_j^2 - b_j^2| \leq \|a - b\|_{1} (\|a\|_{1} + \|b\|_{1}), $$

and so, $T$ is a well-defined function $\ell^1(\mathbb{N}) \to [0, \infty)$ that is locally Lipschitz and hence continuous. In particular, the inverse image of a closed set under $T$ is also closed. Now,

$$ \left\{a \in \ell^1(\mathbb{N}) \,\middle|\, \sum |a_j|^2 \leq 1 \right\} = T^{-1}([0, 1]) $$

and

$$ \left\{a \in \ell^1(\mathbb{N}) \,\middle|\, \sum |a_j|^2 < \infty \right\} = T^{-1}([0, \infty)) = \ell^1(\mathbb{N}). $$

Comment: Marked as the answer because it gives a general approach that can be applied to other sets in the future. Completely forgot I could use the topological definition of continuity since I was working in functional analysis, but this is very useful!

Comment: But, shouldn't the last line be $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$? After all, the set of sequences with finite $L_2$ norm is $\ell^2$, not $\ell^1$.

Comment: @ClosedLimelikeCurves, The computation can be easily modified to show that every element of $\ell^1$ also lies in $\ell^2$. (This is why the function $T$ is well-defined on $\ell^1$.)

Answer (score 0):

The second set is the whole space $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$; this is easily seen by Hölder's inequality:
$$
\|a\|_2^2 \leq \|a\|_1 \|a\|_\infty < \infty, 
$$
since if $a \in \ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ then necessarily $\|a\|_\infty < \infty$.

For the first set, say $a^{(j)} \to a$ in $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ with $\|a^{(j)}\|_2 \leq 1$ for all $j$. To show $\|a\|_2 \leq 1$ it suffices to show that $a^{(j)} \to a$ in $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. For this, one can use
$$
\|a^{(j)} - a\|_2^2 \leq \|a^{(j)} - a\|_1 (\|a^{(j)}\|_1 + \|a\|_1), 
$$
where we use $(u-v)^2 \leq |u - v|(|u| + |v|)$.  Evidently the righthand side vanishes as $j \to \infty$, as needed.